# Efficient XQuery query to determine the documents where an element does NOT exist

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

Let's say I have ~50 million records in a collection like this:

```
<record>
  <some_data>
    <some_data_id>112423425345235</some_data_id>
  </some_data>
</record>
```

So I have maybe a million records (bad data) that look like this:

```
<record>
  <some_data>
  </some_data>
</record>
```

With some_data element being empty.
So if I have an `element-range-index` setup on **some_data_id**, what's an efficient XQuery query that will give me all the empty ones to delete?

I think what I'm looking for is a query that is not a **FLWOR** where you check the existence of children records for each  element, as I think that is inefficient (i.e. pulling the data back and then filtering)?

Whereas if I did it in the `cts:search` query then it would be more efficient, as in filter the data before pulling it back?

Please write a query that can do this efficiently and confirm whether or not my assumptions about **FLWOR** statements are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need a range index to do this efficiently. Using the "universal" element indexes via `cts:query` constructors should be fine:

```
cts:element-query(xs:QName('record'),
  cts:element-query(xs:QName('some_data'),
    cts:not-query(cts:element-query(xs:QName('some_data_id'), cts:and-query(())))
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was checking the length of the children in a FLWOR statement and it was terrible. This is exponentially faster.

Comment: You might also want to try `cts:element-query(xs:QName('some_data_id'), cts:or-query(())))` instead of the not-query. There is a subtle difference in behavior..